# Matrix Decomposition

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, linear-algebra

I have a square n*n matrix S that has to be decomposed into a product of two matrices - A1 and A2, where A2 is transposed matrix to A1 (A2=A1^T) , so A1 * A2 = S. Are there any algorithms to do such operation effectively? C#/C++ solution would be nice.

Comment: This is probably part of a larger algorithm, few do linear algebra for fun :) If you want to include the case where S is not symmetric then you should also add the bigger problem.
Otherwise, add a check for symmetry at the beginning of your algorithm, it will save a lot of calculations.

Comment: I'm doing some statistics research and at some point find a covariance matrix, with which i must perform such manipulations. Actually, it has to be symmetric, but at this moment it is not (despite the fact all formulas are correct)... It seems like i need to dig deeper into the code before manipulation with matrices. Anyway thanks for proposed approach, this might be it.

Comment: As I understand it, covariance matrices *must* be symmetric, within the limits of machine precision and accumulated error.  If you are getting a covariance matrix that is obviously asymmetric, something is probably fundamentally wrong with your code.

Comment: For sequence X={x1,x2,...xn}; xmean=(x1+...+xn)/n i use formula Sigma(i,j) = i==j ? (1/(n-1)) * pow(xi-xmean,2) : (1/(n-1)) * (xi-xmean)*(xj-xmean), is that right? Sigma(i,j) - covariance between xi and xj, Sigma(i,j)(i=j) = dispersion of xi (diagonal elements of matrix)...

Comment: one more link for you : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CovarianceMatrix.html .It looks like you don't need the 1/(n-1) factor, but I'm no expert. Also, both this and your formula should give a symmetric matrix, if it doesn't then check your implementation again.

Answer (score 3):

As Andrei suggested, it seems you are trying to do Cholesky Decomposition.

There is provided C++ code in [polish wiki site for it](http://pl.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rozk%C5%82ad_Choleskiego&oldid=21970223).

There is also separate subsection in "Numerical recipes in C" (2.9 Cholesky decomposition, can be found here: http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf/c2-9.pdf )

Answer (score 2):

In that case you probably want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: +1: I was about to add the same link for the new version of the question.

Comment: @Singularity: Use (AB)^T = B^T.A^T and see that if such a decomposition is possible then S = S^T.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do but

[here is the GSL lib that might help](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)

14 Linear Algebra